# How to avoid floating-point too small error in TCL

Tags: math, floating-point, tcl

I would like to calculate an expression including exponential.

But when I try to evaluate an expression like :
    `exp(-1.0e3)`

I get an error message saying :
    `"floating point value too small to represent"`

How can I avoid this?

I just want to get 0.0 when value is too small to represent.

Comment: What Tcl version are you using? I don't have this error on Tcl 8.5.11.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Tcl are you using? What platform are you on? It works for me (on OSX):

```
$ tclsh8.4
% expr exp(-1.0e3)
0.0
% info patchlevel
8.4.19
```

```
$ tclsh8.5
% expr exp(-1.0e3)
0.0
% info patchlevel
8.5.9
```

```
$ tclsh8.6
% expr exp(-1.0e3)
0.0
% info patchlevel
8.6.1
```

It also works just fine when I put that value in a variable and use that, and I've checked that Tcl is understanding it as a (moderately) large negative number and some much larger negative numbers as well (`-1e100`).

Comment: Thanks. It's working in recent version. I was using too old version (8.0 and 8.3).

Comment: Oooh, they're really old. I remember switching _to_ 8.0 back about 15 years ago, and 8.4 just had its final patch release (8.4.20) this summer…